# IE11 compatible Object.fromEntries

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm looking to make my ES6 JavaScript code compatible with IE11, but I'm having some issues.

**Here is the return for `var res` inside Google Chrome**:
[image]

Tip: category is the key, result[category] is the value.

**Here is the code that I have**:

```
for (var category in result) {
    var res = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(result[category]).filter(x => x !== 'Other').concat('Other').map(x => [x, result[category][x]]));
    console.log(res);
}
```

Could someone guide me in the right direction on how I would be able to make `var res` compatible with IE11? Looks like `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.keys` might not be supported.

Comment: A polyfill of `Object.fromEntries` is available in [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-object) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: @evolutionxbox, let's say that I'm not using node_modules, but this is a `$(document).ready(function() {` script with an `$.ajax({}) call` inside a `HTML` file, how could I use a polyfill?

Comment: https://vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/objectfromentries/ - all I'm searching is "Object.fromEntries polyfill"

Comment: Polyfilling `Object.fromEntries` requires a proper implementation of [iterations protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), which are quite complicated to write yourself. I highly suggest rethinking your current development approach if you don't want to run into compatibility issues later on, and just use core-js to provide the polyfills you need.

Comment: @evolutionxbox IE11 does not support `for...of` syntax (or `let`, or destructuring).

Comment: A screenshot of textual data is rarely helpful for search engines or people with visual impairments. Please provide text.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sure thing. I'm just giving ideas.

Comment: You've heard it before, but at some point fighting the good fight against IE [becomes the lesser of two evil tasks](https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer). Good luck.

Comment: @isherwood, unfortunately, if I could burn IE11 I would, but corporate life wants IE11 to work since users still use it :\

Comment: That's the same tired argument. Email that article. Right now. Do it. I was successful at my bank, where selling any tech is a chore. You can be a hero too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can polyfill `Object.fromEntries` using a simple `for` loop.

```js
function fromEntries(entries){
    var res = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) res[entries[i][0]] = entries[i][1];
    return res;
}
if(!Object.fromEntries) Object.fromEntries = fromEntries;
console.log(fromEntries([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]))
```

Comment: This actually works and produces the same result that `Object.fromEntries` would in the console! Thanks man! I still don't get a console.log result back in IE11, so I would think that something with either `Object.keys` or `.map` isn't supported, but this solved the Object.fromEntries part.

Comment: @SLE Happy to help.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for all iterables, only array-like entries. Though creating non-array-like iterables in IE11 would be very uncommon without code that was transpiled.